# Ajax content not displaying on IE7 & 8 - WORKS on IE9 & FF

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I'm trying to load some content (same domain) into a div. It works perfectly in FF and IE9, however, IE7 and 8 display nothing. After a couple of days of trial and error with all possible solutions found here and elsewhere, i really need some help. This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" charset="utf-8">
</script>

<div id="test">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#test').load('http://localhost/abc2012/competitie/team.php?teamID=3');
</script>
</div>
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Do you get any errors? What is the response of `http://localhost/abc2012/competitie/team.php?teamID=3`?

Comment: have you inspected the request in IE developer console? Best guess is you have some malformed html that other browsers are more tolerant with if the request is being made successfully. Can also implement some jQuery AJAX error handling  http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/

Comment: Thank for you reply. No errors reported. It's a php file with some tables with competition ranknings.

Comment: post a link to live page

Comment: Actually its a new site i'm developping locally using Xampp. I'll try to include the code in the old online website.

Comment: I included the code at the bottom of our old website: http://www.ffs-vegelinsoord.nl/ It's the rankings and results in blue, please ignore the styling (css files missing). I can see the loaded content on FF and IE9, but again not on IE7 & IE8. Am I missing something??

Answer (score 0):

try putting your 'load' script into a [jQuery document ready](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aIntroducing_%24%28document%29.ready%28%29) block

Comment: Okay I tried your method. After implementing (competitie.js) I receive an error: Breaking on JScript runtime error - Object doesn't support this property or method (line 4)... FF and IE9 still display fine. Thanks for your help anyway.